# Time and space complexity of solution to combination problem

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

**Problem statement:**

> Given two integers `n` and `k`, return all possible combinations of `k` numbers out of the range `[1, n]`, inclusive.

**Sample input and desired output:**

```
Input: n = 4, k = 2
Output:
[
  [2,4],
  [3,4],
  [2,3],
  [1,2],
  [1,3],
  [1,4],
]
```

Here are 2 correct backtracking solutions I came up with where the second applies an optimization which I think reduces the time/space complexity:

```py
def combine(self, n: int, k: int) -> List[List[int]]:
    def backtrack(curr, n, partial_res, res):
        if len(partial_res) == k:
            res.append(partial_res[:])
            return
        
        for i in range(curr, n+1):
            partial_res.append(i)
            backtrack(i+1, n, partial_res, res)
            partial_res.pop()
    
    res = []
    backtrack(1, n, [], res)
    return res
```

```py
def combine(self, n: int, k: int) -> List[List[int]]:
    def backtrack(curr, n, partial_res, res):
        if len(partial_res) == k:
            res.append(partial_res[:])
            return
        
        for i in range(curr, n+1):
            # bailing out early if the path can't produce valid results
            if k - len(partial_res) > n+1 - curr: continue
            partial_res.append(i)
            backtrack(i+1, n, partial_res, res)
            partial_res.pop()
    
    res = []
    backtrack(1, n, [], res)
    return res
```

I'm having a hard time to come up with the correct lower bound of the time complexity. Here's what I got so far:

```
(n+1-k) + (n+1-k-1) + (n+1-k-2)... + ... (n+1-k-(n-k))
(n+1-k) + (n-k)     + (n-k-1)  ... + ... (n+1-k-n+k)
(n+1-k) + ... + ...                      (1)
(1)     + (2) + ... + (n-k+1)
this implies:
(n-k+1) * (n-k+2) / 2
```

It follows that the time complexity is `O((n-k)^2)`.

I'm absolutely not sure about my calculations. In addition I don't know how it would be for the first solution without the optimization. Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: For the first solution it should be `(n!/(n-k)!)`=`O(n^k)` for the second one it would be `n choose k` = `n!/(k! * n-k!)` which would be equivalent to `O(min(n^k, n^(n-k)))` in terms of `n`

Comment: It looks too high to me for the second approach. Say `n=4, k=2`, we get `[[1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [2,3], [2,4], [3,4]]`.  This is 6. Equivalent to `1 + 2 + (n-k+1) = 1+2+3`. `(n-k+1)^2 = 9` which is a more accurate bound. `min(n^k, n^(n-k)) = min(16, 16) = 16. @Jay

Comment: I think your `n!/(k! * (n-k)!)` gives correct result though. `2*3*4/(2 * 2) = 2*3 = 6` @Jay

Comment: For the second one the exact limit is indeed `n!/(k! * (n-k)!)` but in terms of big O notation it would be equivalent to `O(min(n^k, n^(n-k)))`. e.g. for `n!` operations, the big O complexity would be `n^n` as there is no way to put an upper bound to `n!` in polynomial time apart from `n^n`

Comment: `O((n-k+1)^2)` gives me a lower limit for `n!/(k! * (n-k)!)`. I can't prove the path from the second expression to the first mathematically, but I know it should work from the Gauss method that I did by example in my question. Appreciate if you can show me if I'm correct or wrong in that process. Thanks @Jay

Comment: Your `backtrack(1, ..)` is calling `backtrack(2,..)` `n` times, each of which in turn call `backtrack(3,..)` `n-1` times, so the recurrence here is not what you explained using the Gauss method. For 2nd solution, its going to be `n*(n-1)*(n-2)...(n-k)` (given you are using `break` instead of `continue` and k < n/2) otherwise its going to be `n*(n-1)*(n-2)...(k)`. While for the first solution its going to be `n*(n-1)*(n-2)...(n-k)` since we stop when our list reaches length `k`

Comment: Got it, thanks @Jay What confused me and made me doubt my calculations was the use of `continue` instead of `break` on my part. My calculations were for `break` but the code used `continue`. Much appreciate your input.

Comment: BTW, if you want to make it an answer, I'd gladly accept @Jay

Comment: Since nothing in `if k - len(partial_res) > n+1 - curr` depends on the loop variable, it will evaluate to the same boolean on every iteration, which makes putting it inside the loop pointless. You could save a whole lot of work by only doing the loop if the test succeeds. But that's not optimal either; better would be to not call backtrack if the test was going to fail, which you could do by simply changing the limit of the range in that very same for loop.